# Facebook OAuth login redirects to facebook.com instead of my website when auth_type is set to reauthenticate

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am using Laravel 5 OAuth plugin.

```
public function loginFacebook(Request $request){
    $code = $request->get('code');
    $facebookService = \OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

    if (!is_null($code)) {
        $token = $facebookService->requestAccessToken($code);

        $fb_access_token = $token->getAccessToken();

        ...
    }
    else {
        $url = $facebookService->getAuthorizationUri(['auth_type' => 'reauthenticate', 'redirect_uri' => url('/login/facebook')]);
        return redirect((string)$url);
    }
}
```

After clicking the login button, it redirects me to a page which asks me to retype my password. After clicking proceed, it then redirects me to facebook home (feed) instead of my website.

Comment: Follow this URL: https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel and see where you do a mistake?

Comment: If you want to add Facebook authentication to your app, you can use the Socialite package for that.